# Event on image load - custom image from user defined url / input - load() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-input, jquery-load, imageurl

I want to achieve a simple event (html change in `span`) when image from custom / user defined url gets loaded.

http://jsfiddle.net/n2m8u5xb/3/

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    $(this).html('loading...'); //works
    $('#img').css("backgroundImage", "url('"+$("#img-url").html()+"')");
    $('#img-url').html(url('"+$("#img-url").html()+"'));
});
$('#img').load(function(){
    $('#btn').html('Go'); //doesn't work
});
```

This `load()` function doesn't work. I also tried with `if` `else` in the click function.

So how in this case to detect custom image load and how to trigger the event?

here are some random large images for quick testing (smallest - largest):

http://i.imgur.com/tJVDlKz.jpg

http://i.imgur.com/NZllSc0.jpg

http://photojournal.jpl.nasa.gov/jpeg/PIA13932.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use an "img" tag for this, or if you insist on using background-image, you can first load it via javascript and then place it as css

something like this:

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
$(this).html('loading...');

var img = new Image(),
url = $("#img-url").html();
img.onload = function () { 
   $('#img').css("backgroundImage", "url('"+url+"')");
   $('#btn').html('Go');
};
img.src = url;

$('#img-url').html("url('"+url+"')");
});
```